# Среднее арифметическое из 10 рандомных чисел

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Задание: найти среднее арифметическое из 10 рандомных чисел в пределах от 1 до 40. Проблема в том что не хочет компилироваться после добавления вот этой строчки `sum += r;`.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, r, sum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        r = 1 + rand() % (40 - 1);
        sum += r;
        cout << r << endl;
    }
    cout << "Average" << sum/10;
}
```

Comment: Надо инициализировать переменные. int i=0, r=0, sum=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилируется - но с предупреждением об использовании неинициализированной переменной `sum`.

Судите сами - вы объявили `sum` без инициализации. Т.е. в ней какой-то мусор. После этого прибавляете к мусору значение `r` - и какой в нем смысл, если неизвестно, к чему вы, его, собственно, прибавляете?..

Comment: Да, действительно. Благодарю ;)

Comment: Да я просто перевел для вас сообщение компилятора, на которое вы не обратили внимания...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала: а что вы делаете в этой строчке? Вы прибавляете к числу... которое равняется непонятно чему, так как вы его не проинициализировали. И впредь приводите вашу "ошибку".

А вообще разбор кода:

```
#include "pch.h"//зачем?
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>//зачем?
using namespace std;// плохая вещь, если используете, то лучше локально
int main()
{
int i, r, sum;// инициализация где?
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {// в с принято вести отсчет от 0, i++ может быть медленнее чем ++i
    r = 1 + rand() % (40 - 1);
    sum += r;
    cout << r << endl;
}
cout << "Average" << sum/10;// у вас получится целое число, что, я думаю, сдесь не уместно, лучше использовать sum/10.f - так вы получите дробное число.
}//где return?
```